# java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$PredefTypeCreator

Tags: java, apache-spark-mllib

When I learn ALS, I execute the `ml/ALSExample.scala`.However, when I execute

```
Dataset<Row> userRecs = model.recommendForAllUsers(10);
userRecs.show();
```

it tips

> Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$PredefTypeCreator
>   Serialization stack:
>       - object not serializable (class: scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$PredefTypeCreator, value: scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$PredefTypeCreator@649dd078)
>       - writeObject data (class: scala.reflect.api.SerializedTypeTag)
>       - object (class scala.reflect.api.SerializedTypeTag, scala.reflect.api.SerializedTypeTag@4b377643)
>       - writeReplace data (class: scala.reflect.api.SerializedTypeTag)
>       - object (class scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$PredefTypeTag, TypeTag[Int])
>       - field (class: org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.TopByKeyAggregator, name: org$apache$spark$ml$recommendation$TopByKeyAggregator$$evidence$2, type: interface scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$TypeTag)

Comment: actually,it is ml/ALSExample.java.sorry